# Behaviour of Japanese IME

Tags: windows-7, input-languages, ime, japanese

```
OS:  Windows 7
IME: Both Google Japanese IME and Microsoft IME
```

When using my IME, it behaves rather odd. When typing in one window/field - i.e. the Google search bar in Firefox - it behaves as expected; when I type 'd', followed by 'e', it gives me 'd' at first, then changes to the Hiragana 'で'. However, when I type in other windows, it gives me 'し', instead of a 'd'. Then second character gives another Hiragana.

Anyone knows what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the IME switches to the kana mode when type in the "other window".

I don't know what cause this, but maybe you can try to reset the IME setting?

**Edited:**

I found some Japanese web sites complaining about the same issue.
A quick fix is using `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Caps Lock` to switch between Romaji mode and Kana mode.

Comment: No, it's in Hiragana mode in both cases.

Comment: What I mean is the difference between romaji mode and kanamode.
In romaji mode, you input kana with its romanization.
In kana mode, you input kana with its keyboard mapping, which can be seen on the Japanese keyboard.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had a Kanji mode - which explains my confusion.